# HTTP status code for GET requests when entity is corrupted

Tags: rest, error-handling, api-design, http-status-codes

How should servers respond to `GET` requests for corrupted entities?

Let's say I have a Person schema

```
Person {
  firstName: optional string
  lastName: required string
}
```

And due to an issue in the database or due to a bug in CREATE implementation, certain `Person` entities with missing `lastName` got created.

When a client is doing a GET call to fetch such an entity, how should the server respond?

Here are a few options I can think of:

1. Throw a 4XX

   It’s the client’s issue since they shouldn’t be fetching invalid entities. 400/422 both feel incorrect here since the request syntax is valid.
2. Throw a 500

   It’s our (server) issue since at some point we allowed the creation of an invalid entity or something happened on server/DB end where data got corrupted. Either way, not really a client's problem.
3. Return the entity with the missing lastName

   This feels hacky as it essentially means the server isn't following the contract it has specified.

All the above feel somewhat hacky. Is there a better HTTP error for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

> The *500 (Internal Server Error)* status code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. -- [HTTP Semantics](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.6.1)

The server having lost or corrupted data certainly sounds like an "unexpected condition".

Of course, [500](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.6.1) can mean lots of different things; so if you want to share more information with the end consumer, you should include that information in the body of the response:

> the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.

But the general purpose components of the HTTP application don't really care which unexpected condition prevented the server from fulfilling the request, so 500 is sufficient for all of them.